# Find the sum of cubes in Scala

Tags: list, scala

I want to code a function in Scala that takes two integers and sums the cube of every value in the inclusive range of those two integers.

For example, I call:

```
sumCubes(0,2)
```

I must get the result **9** because (0^3+1^3+2^3) = 9.

I have to use the `range` method and consider this template:

```
def sumCubes2(x: Int, y: Int)= {
@annotation.tailrec
def fAux(acc: Int,xs: List[Int]): Int= ???
???
}
```

I thought about creating a list with the elements in the range of the two integers and another variable that will contain the final result:

```
var rangeList = List.range(x, y)
var finalValue = 0
```

Now I don't know if I should use a for loop or call recursively the function fAux somehow.

Comment: `x*x*x` is the cube of `x`, not the cube root.

Comment: `(x to y) map (i => i*i*i) sum`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using your template:

```
def sumCubes2(x: Int, y: Int)= {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def fAux(acc: Int,xs: List[Int]): Int= xs match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: xx => fAux(x*x*x + acc, xx)
  }
  fAux(0, (x to y).toList)
}
```

But this makes more sense:

```
(x to y).fold(0){case (a,b) => a + b*b*b}
```

Comment: "It can be done using your template" Of course it can, because the assignment question gave the template, I expect.

Comment: The answer is yes, @The Archetypal Paul.
Anyway, jwvh's solution worked just great.

Comment: OK. Personally, I feel assignments should be completed with one's own efforts, not getting someone else to write it for you

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it like this, I don't know whether the map function is optimized for `tail recursion`,anyway:

```
(a to b).map(x=>x*x*x).sum


scala> (0 to 2).map(x=>x*x*x).sum
res160: Int = 9

scala> (2 to 5).map(x=>x*x*x).sum
res161: Int = 224

scala>
```